# Azure Logic App For Each loop sending multiple emails each time want to send only one email instead

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app, that reads from a sql server. I want it to get the rows from the database and send the data obtained via email.

The problem am having it is sending the email in a foreach loop, which will cause poblems for me in the future, when the data in the database grows.

So instead I want the logic apps to gather all the data into one email and send,
How can I go about that?

Comment: Set a variable before the for loop,
append the value of variable in the foreach loop (email payload)
once foreach loop is finished after that send the email using the variable populated in the foreach loop

Comment: @SujitSingh, Okay How will I do that in the azure logic apps?